# C# : How to indicate that a supposedly unused method is being used from outside the project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using `Unity` in combination with other platforms such as `Android` and `iOS`. There are methods in my Unity script that are called from `Android` or `iOS` such as

```
public void ApplyEffect()
{
    //Some code
}
```

This method is only called from `Android` or `iOS` and not referenced within the Unity code. As a result, I see the warning

```
Method 'ApplyEffect' is never used
```

But more importantly, these methods are confusing to other people as it gives the impression that these methods aren't being used.

I would like to have a way to indicate that these methods are being used so that someone doesn't remove them by mistake. I feel having some representation would make the code more readable too. But how do I do it?

Jetbrains Rider has a `UsedImplicitly` annotation which looks perfect but I think it may not work on other editors. Commenting is one option but that doesn't seem like a good solution.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `#pragma warning disable (err nbr)` and `#pragma warning restore (err nbr)` around the code to signal your intent to other developers.

Answer (score 3):

I think this warning is only thrown by ReSharper itself, and is not a native C# warning.

As you already mentioned you can use the [`[UsedImplicitly]`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#UsedImplicitlyAttribute) attribute from ReSharper to rid of the warning, but as you noted people not using ReSharper or Jetbrains won't know what that attribute is for, but will also not get the warning in the first place. So it will then still require a comment explaining what the attribute does and why it is there (at which point you can just have a comment explain that it is used there in the first place)

Another option (Just for JetBrains/ReSharper users) is to turn off the [`solution-wide analysis`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis.html) which should stop ReSharper from checking for that warning, but that may not be a satiscatory solution, as you're probably using it because you want the functionality.

A more targeted solution would be to place [`// ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#suppress) at the very start of your method `ApplyEffect`, which should disable the warning for just that method, while still looking pretty clear for non-ReSharper users.

In short, since it is a ReSharper/Jetbrains warning to begin with it requires a ReSharper/Jetbrains solution, the only "Global" solution would be commenting that the method is actually used, and where it is called from. (Which in my personal opinion is the way to go)